# How to approximate all values in the formula？

Tags: simplifying-expressions, approximation

Given

```
E^(t (4.285 - 0.5 Sqrt[1.9994 - 4. wn]))
```

How do I simplify the formula to `E^(t (4.2 - 0.5 Sqrt[1.9 - 4. wn]))`?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960114/how-do-you-round-decimal-of-an-expression-in-mathematica)

Comment: Wouldn't one prefer that the numbers be rounded rather than floored?

Comment: Thank you. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Lukas' comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176229/how-to-approximate-all-values-in-the-formula#comment462493_176229), you can replace all `Real` numbers with their rounded version to whatever precision you'd like.

In this case, it appears that you want the floor of those numbers though, so:

```
E^(t (4.285 - 0.5 Sqrt[1.9994 - 4. wn])) /. x_Real :> Floor[x, 0.1]
(* Out: E^(t (4.2 - 0.5 Sqrt[1.9 - 4. wn])) *)
```

As [Daniel mentioned](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176229/how-to-approximate-all-values-in-the-formula#comment462511_176229), if you'd rather round them, which you might, this would be easy enough using the same technique:

```
E^(t (4.285 - 0.5 Sqrt[1.9994 - 4. wn])) /. x_Real :> Round[x, 0.1]
(* Out: E^(t (4.3 - 0.5 Sqrt[2. - 4. wn])) *)
```

Finally, consider `Rationalize` as well: this will automatically thread over arguments, and will give an arbitrary precision version of the expression, which you can always numericize (e.g. with `N`) when needed:

```
Rationalize[E^(t (4.285 - 0.5 Sqrt[1.9994 - 4. wn]))]
(* Out: E^(t (857/200 - (1/2) Sqrt[9997/5000 - 4 wn])) *)
```